# Comparing two tables in Excel and hiding rows

Tags: vba, excel

The goal of my code is to compare two columns in tables within two different sheets. If the values of each cell in each column are the same, then the row in one column is hidden. I keep getting the Type Mismatch error for this line: `If myCob2 = myCodes Then`

Also, is it possible to compare a column in a table in one sheet and just a regular column (not in a table) in another sheet? Thank you!

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AstInv()
Dim myLibros As ListObject
Dim myInventory As ListObject
Dim myCob2 As Range
Dim myCodes As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set myLibros = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Libros").ListObjects("Table_1")
Set myInventory = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory").ListObjects("Table2")
Set myCob2 = myLibros.ListColumns("COB2").Range
Set myCodes = myInventory.ListColumns("Codes").Range

If myCob2 = myCodes Then

    For Each cell In myCob2

    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare two ranges instead of values.  To compare each cell in one list against a value in another list you can use nested loops.

Try this:

```
For Each cobCell In myCob2
    For Each codeCell In myCodes
        If cobCell = codeCell Then
            cobCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next codeCell
Next cobCell
```

---

Test data:

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looping wrong. Should you not loop first and then do an if statement?

Also, I guess you should check for each cell if the value is in any of the other cells, which means you probably need a double loop.

I suggest you print out `myCob2` and `myCodes` and check what you are actually comparing in your `if`.